# Schematics python multiple object in list

Tags: python, python-schematics

I have defined models in schematics like this:

```
class A(Model):
   value: StringType = StringType(required=True)

class B(Model):
   type: StringType = StringType(required=True)
```

and I want to have this two model types defined in one List something like this:

```
class C(Model):
   list_of_values: ListType = ListType(ModelType(A), ModelType(B), required=True)
```

Can someone help me how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use [PolyModelType](https://schematics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/types.html#schematics.types.compound.PolyModelType) for this.
Something like the following (untested) code:

```
class C(Model):
    list_of_values = ListType(PolyModelType([A, B]), required=True)
```